# How to add custom library in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta

I have updated to Xcode 9 and now trying to add SwiftyJson to my project. However, since there is a new interface for Xcode 9, I have no idea where to add this library.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try using a dependency manager like https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, you are using Cocoapods. Assuming you are executing `pod install` appropriately when SwiftyJSON to your Podfile, you don't need to do anything else in Xcode. Simply `import SwiftyJSON` in the file you're attempting to use it in and you should be all set.

Additionally, all of the methods listed in SwiftyJSON's [read me](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration) are still applicable to Xcode 9.

Finally, Xcode 9's interface for managing a project/target is not that different at all. I think you're problem is that you have the project selected, but you want to be looking inside your target instead.

[image]